# YOCTO Kirkstone : Dotnet 5 : Openssl version

Tags: .net-core, openssl, yocto

I am attempting to get a dotnet - core 5 app to run on yocto kirkstone. BUt I get an impropper ssl version warning.

Things I have tried.

- pulling in an openssl 1 .bb file from previous yocto build.: Gives me a _hashlib error when building python. :D
- telling the dotnet 5 app to only listen on an HTTP port. : No help no change.
- trying to convince dotnet app developer to switch to 6 he is not sure that 6 will solve the problem either.

any other hints or suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean with hashlib error? I was able to run openssl 1.1. from Dunfell on a system using yocto kirkstone. Of course it requires to modify the recipe for openssl 1.1 to make it compile with kirkstone. Also, I renamed the openssl recipe for 1.1 to "openssl-dunfell" so that other recipes don't depend on it.

Comment: You then need to modify the "openssl-dunfell" recipe so that it produces only the .so file and does not deploy header-files etc, otherwise you would get a conflict with the normal openssl recipe from kirkstone.

Comment: It would help if you would copy-paste the exact "hashlib error" you are getting.